# How to identify an element with a specific text and a specific title using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the following DOM

```
<a class="js-sku-link sku-link" title="Inno 3D GeForce RTX 3080 10GB GDDR6X X3 LHR Κάρτα Γραφικών PCI-E x16 4.0 με HDMI και 3 DisplayPort" data-e2e-testid="sku-price-link" href="/s/35993359/Inno-3D-GeForce-RTX-3080-10GB-GDDR6X-X3-LHR-%CE%9A%CE%AC%CF%81%CF%84%CE%B1-%CE%93%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8E%CE%BD-PCI-E-x16-4-0-%CE%BC%CE%B5-HDMI-%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9-3-DisplayPort-N30803-106X-1810VA44H.html">
    <span>από</span>
    871,28 €
</a>
```

As you can see it has a class and a title. There are other elements in the page that have the same a class (`js-sku-link sku-link`) but I want to be able to define based on the title which one I want. In this case I want the one that it has in title the text `RTX 3080`. I tried the following without any luck

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-e2e-testid="sku-price-link" and text()="RTX 3080"]').text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='6950']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath expression:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-e2e-testid="sku-price-link" and contains(@title,"RTX 3080")]').text
```

The result is the text content of the `<a>` element:

> από
> 871,28 €

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML:

```
<a class="js-sku-link sku-link" title="Inno 3D GeForce RTX 3080 10GB GDDR6X X3 LHR Κάρτα Γραφικών PCI-E x16 4.0 με HDMI και 3 DisplayPort" data-e2e-testid="sku-price-link" href="/s/35993359/Inno-3D-GeForce-RTX-3080-10GB-GDDR6X-X3-LHR-%CE%9A%CE%AC%CF%81%CF%84%CE%B1-%CE%93%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8E%CE%BD-PCI-E-x16-4-0-%CE%BC%CE%B5-HDMI-%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9-3-DisplayPort-N30803-106X-1810VA44H.html">
    <span>από</span>
    871,28 €
</a>
```

The element is an `<a>` tag and a *clickable* element. To identify the **clickable** element based on the partial value of the `title` attribute i.e. ***RTX 3080*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `title`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title*='RTX 3080']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and partial `title`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@title, 'RTX 3080')]")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```